# Show that there is a integer $k$ such that $e_n(P, Q) = 1$ if and only if $P = kQ$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $K$ and $n$ be an integer such that the characteristic of the field does not divide $n$. Let $e_n: E[n] \times E[n] \rightarrow \mu_n$ be the Weil pairing and $P$ a point of order $n$. Show that there is an integer $k$ such that $e_n(P, Q) = 1$ if and only if $Q = kP$.

This in an exercise in a book. One side of the proof is easy: if $Q = kP$ then

$$\begin{split}
e_n(P, Q) &= e_n(P, kP)\\
&= e_n(P,P)^k\\
&= 1
\end{split}
$$

no matter what $k$ we choose.

I'm having problems with the other implication. My reasoning is the following: since $P$ has order $n$ it must be the generator of one of the cycles in $E[n] = \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$. Then we have a base $\{P, R\}$ for $E[n]$ and we can write $Q = c_1 P + c_2 R$. Thus,

$$\begin{split}
e_n(P,Q) &= e_n(P,c_1 P + c_2 R)\\
&= e_n(P,P)^{c_1} \cdot e_n(P, R)^{c_2}\\
&=e_n(P, R)^{c_2}
\end{split}$$

So $e_n(P,Q)$ may be $1$ even if the $Q$ is not even a multiple of $P$ depending on the value of $e_n(P,R)$. What am i missing?

Comment: The pairing is non-degenerate.

Comment: For a basis $\{P,R\}$, $e_n(P,R)$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity. So if $e_n(P,Q)=1$, then $n|c_2$, so $c_2R=0$, so $Q=c_1P$, where $1\leq c_1\leq n-1$ is an integer.

Comment: Thanks @Ang, that solves it.